# How can I access object value that is inside the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined
```

from console.log(props.searchedLocation.totalPages.page).

The below object is the console log of 'props.searchedLocation'.

```
{
  next: { page: 3, limit: 10 },
  previous: { page: 1, limit: 10 },
  totalPages: { page: 32 },
  results: [
    {
    },
   ]
}
```

It returns {page: 32} when I do console.log('props.searchedLocation.totalPages'). However, I need the page number to pass it to my pagination component and I'd tried using '?' to search page value but it did not work.

How can I take the value of the object inside of the main object in React or JS?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!props.searchedLocation) {
      setLastPage(100);
    } else {
      setLastPage(props.searchedLocation.totalPages.page);
    }
  }, [props.searchedLocation]);
```

this returns

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined
```

Comment: I can'r see 'searchedLocation' in your sample, Please Provide sample -- "props" object.

Comment: `props.searchedLocation.totalPages` is undefined when you invoke `console.log()`

Comment: you must add code of your component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing the `searchedLocation` properly. The console is showing `totalpages` has object of `page` inside it.

The **easiest** and **reliable** way way is use `searchedLocation.totalPages.page`

```js
const searchedLocation = {
  next: {
    page: 3,
    limit: 10
  },
  previous: {
    page: 1,
    limit: 10
  },
  totalPages: {
    page: 32
  },
  results: [{}, ]
}

console.log(searchedLocation.totalPages.page); //32
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access to the page property

```js
console.log(props.searchedLocation.totalPages.page)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have forgotten to add the page property using dot notation.

It should look as follows:

```
props.searchedLocation.totalPages.page // returns page number as 32
```

using bracket notation:

```
props.searchedLocation.totalPages['page'] // returns page number as 32
```

where as what you had written:

```
props.searchedLocation.totalPages // returns totalPage object as {page: 32}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be used as a dynamic property

like this

```
console.log(props.searchedLocation.totalPages['page'])
```